# How to get around the (Access is denied) to a folder that your java program is saving a file to?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I was wondering if someone could help me find a good resource to help me fix this issue. I'm trying to create/save a batch file in the startups folder. Here's the general path: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\startup_PMA_popup_check.bat`

I've read a lot of things saying that I should simply elevate the privileges of my java program.
I read that if I was to make my jar file a windows executable, then the rights of the program are automatically elevated to admin privileges.

What you're seeing below is my jar turned into an exe and run. The error I got was the same error as the one I got from running my jar. I no longer think that the problem is simply giving my program admin privilege.

I performed a test outside of my program by going to this path and attempting to move a file into the folder. Assuming I'd have no issue "since I am root already", I went ahead expecting to get no prompts. What I got was a popup saying that I needed to confirm that I was Admin & to confirm that I wanted to put the batch file in the folder.

My question is how should I make my java program issue this prompt to the user or something so my program can continue & not crash like shown below??:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\StartUp\startup_PMA_popup_check.bat (Access is denied)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.PrintWriter.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.PrintWriter.(Unknown Source)
>           at prioritymanagementassistant.Background.createBatchFile(Background.java:106)
>           at prioritymanagementassistant.Main.main(Main.java:930)

Thank You for your time,

Comment: Run it as Administrator.

Comment: It just gave me the same error

Comment: Save it to a different folder then, since the one thing that absolutely would work apparently didn't work for you.

Comment: @C.K Are you _sure_ you ran it as administrator? You say _"I read that if I was to make my jar file a windows executable, then the rights of the program are automatically elevated to admin privileges"_ but this is not true. You must use the "Run as Administrator" context menu option.

Comment: I recommend that you place the BAT-file for automatic execution on Windows startup in the folder of the (current) user. That way you don't even need administrative privileges. The folder is like "C:\Users\\[name of the user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" and I think there is a system property for the user directory in Java.

Comment: That worked, thank you!